# Use both h5py and pytables in the same Python process

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables, h5py

The two main Python libraries for HDF5 interaction are `h5py` and `pytables`.  They don't play nicely together, particularly on windows

```
>>> import tables
>>> import h5py
ImportError: DLL load failed

>>> import h5py
>>> import tables   # works fine
```

I need to use both in the same application but I'm unable to get full functionality from both libraries when each is imported.  Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I assume the later only works because ``tables`` seems to load dlls lazily. Try opening a file, on my Win64 system that leads to a crash as well.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread on github](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/390) no, I don't think you can. It seems that h5py cannot do anything about it, so I would start an issue with the [pytables github](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues).

Also, could you possibly use two different scripts? That way the import wouldn't bork.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `conda` to install packages? If yes, it looks like [an issue reported on GitHub](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/300). That issue to me seems like an issue with build `0` of version `2.4.0` of `h5py`. Try downgrading to version `2.3.x`. That works just fine for me.